# Pass boolean value to another class

Tags: java, boolean

In my main class I want to check if there was a change by using a boolean variable:

```
public class Main {

    private boolean change = false;

    public boolean getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public void setChange(boolean change) {
        this.change = change;
    }

    private void method1() {
        // some command
        setChange(true);

    method1();
}
```

If I want to get this boolean value in my second class, I always get returned "false", no matter if my method1 ran or not.

```
public class BoolTest {

    Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println(m.getChange()); // returns "false"
}
```

Comment: Are you operating on the same instance of `Main`?

Answer (score 2):

You must have two instances of Main. Use the same one. Example:

```
Main m = new Main();
System.out.println(m.getChange());
m.setChange(true);
System.out.println(m.getChange());
```

You probably want to share the same instance over multiple classes. Pass the instance to the other classes and use them as expected.

Comment: Thanks. How do you mean I need to have two instances of Main? If I run `method1();` in my Main class, I should get returned "true" in my BoolTest class, no?

Comment: i figured when I change boolean variable and getter/setter methods to static it works fine.